# Replicate MySQL 5.0 Master to 5.5 Slave?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.0

We're planning out a series of server/software upgrades and were curious.

We have a RHEL5 install running MySQL 5.0 that we'd like to replicate to a new (virtualized) server running CentOS 6 and MySQL 5.5. Then, in the future, we would bump the RHEL5 machine to CentOS6 and MySQL5.5. We want to get this replication going first if possible.

So the short question is, has anyone tried replicating a MySQL 5.0 master to a 5.5 slave?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done that dozens of times for [**my employer's**](http://www.logicworks.net/tech-specs/high-availability-architectures#database-clustering) clients. In fact, I just did this a week ago. The client was using MySQL 5.0.81 and had degraded performance in InnoDB.

- I create a new DB Cluster

  - running MySQL 5.5.27
  - Two DB Servers (ServerA and ServerB)
  - Configure InnoDB for Multicore Engagement
- Master/Slave (ServerA Master and ServerB Slave)
- I enable [binary logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin) and [log_slave_updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_slave_updates) on Production's Slave
- mysqldump all databases (except mysql schema) from Production's Slave to /root/MySQLData.sql
- run [**pt-show-grants**](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-show-grants.html) on  Production's Master to /root/MySQLGrants.sql
- load ServerA with /root/MySQLGrants.sql
- load ServerA with /root/MySQLData.sql
- I replicate from Production's Slave (MySQL 5.0.81) to ServerA (MySQL 5.5.27)

All that was left to do was

- Have the client shutdown the app
- Remove DBVIP from Master running MySQL 5.0.81
- Bring up DBVIP on Master running MySQL 5.5.27
- Have the client start up the app

## CONCLUSION

MySQL 5.5 can handle replication from previous major releases, and not the other way around.

I have discussed this before

- `Feb 04, 2011` : [MySQL master binlog corruption](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12530/mysql-master-binlog-corruption/12531#12531)
- `Jun 09, 2011` :  [Yum update mysql from 5.1 to 5.5](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12528/yum-update-mysql-from-5-1-to-5-5/12529#12529)
- `Feb 08, 2012` : [will replication from 5.5.20 to 5.0.XX server work?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12509/will-replication-from-5-5-20-to-5-0-xx-server-work/12511#12511)

## GOOD NEWS !!!

I already answered a post back on Feb 06, 2012 ( [How to setup replication(Master/slave) in MySQL 5.5.20?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12345/how-to-setup-replicationmaster-slave-in-mysql-5-5-20/12352#12352) ) with all the steps you need.

BTW with regards to the step about dumping the MYSQL grants as SQL commands, here is my personal emulation of pt-show-grants:

```
mysql -hhostaddr -umyuserid -pmypassword --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql -hhostaddr -umyuserid -pmypassword --skip-column-names -A | sed 's/$/;/g' > MySQLUserGrants.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2012-11-27 11:07 EDT

I wanted to add additional posts I made for setting up Circular Replication should you decide to setup the two DB servers as Master/Master

- `Sep 24, 2012` : [Setting up MySQL circular replication in existing replication topology?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24798/setting-up-mysql-circular-replication-in-existing-replication-topology/24830#24830)
- `May 07, 2012` : [Setting Circular Replication in mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17529/setting-circular-replication-in-mysql/17532#17532)

Comment: Would the steps change much in my case where there is currently only a production master, there are no slaves or second masters? Thank you for this great writeup Rolando, it is very appreciated!

Comment: Do you have binary logging enabled on the production master right now? (If you do not know, login to mysql and run `SHOW MASTER STATUS;`. If you get `Empty set`, then it is off.

Comment: Can you tolerate downtime ???

Comment: Is all you data InnoDB ???

Comment: empty set, and I see everything in Replication/Backup settings is commented out except 'server-id=1'. Also yes we can tolerate downtime, especially during the holiday season which is why this comes up now :). Most data is InnoDB, we do use a few myisam tables for speed where we don't need foreign key checks

Comment: I updated my answer. I already wrote a script several months ago on how to setup replication.

Comment: Thanks Rolando, we should be doing this in about two weeks so I'll post back on (hopefully) the success of your script! Also you asked if the data was InnoDB, does it affect things if it is a mix of InnoDB/MyISAM?

Comment: It simplifies everything because if all data were InnoDB, you explicitly have `server-id=1` in `my.cnf`, and you have binary logging enabled already, you could mysqldump all databases without downtime.